# Rails: How much information to store inside a polymorphic assts model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I am building a Webapp and have a feature called "Movies" and another "Places". Both of them can have a video file. The "Movies" obviously for the movie and "Places" can have a video of recordings of that particular Place.

At the moment i have 2 models, "Video" and "PlacesVideo", which is unnecessary i think and so i want to make 1 polymorphic "Video" Model.

Now each video can have a "poster" associated with it, that's the image you show before playing a video. Should that be stored in the polym. Video model, or separately in "Movie" or "Place" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing is creating a "VideoAsset" model (because my feature is called Videos not "Movies") and storing the video file and poster inside that model.